# ls output differs stdout vs screen

Tags: shell

Look at the diffreent output of `ls` versus `ls -1`

```
$ ls
 filea1.txt   fileb.txt    listB1.xml   listC.xml
 filea.txt    listA1.xml   listB.xml   'name with spaces 2.txt'
 fileb1.txt   listA.xml    listC1.xml  'name with spaces.txt'

$ ls -1
filea1.txt
filea.txt
fileb1.txt
fileb.txt
listA1.xml
listA.xml
listB1.xml
listB.xml
listC1.xml
listC.xml
'name with spaces 2.txt'
'name with spaces.txt'
```

Which is quite OK for me. Thing go different if you redirect the output to file. I'd expect that file diffes, but they are identical.

```
$ ls -1>/tmp/ls-1.out
$ ls >/tmp/ls.out

$ cat /tmp/ls-1.out
filea1.txt
filea.txt
fileb1.txt
fileb.txt
listA1.xml
listA.xml
listB1.xml
listB.xml
listC1.xml
listC.xml
name with spaces 2.txt
name with spaces.txt

$ cat /tmp/ls.out
filea1.txt
filea.txt
fileb1.txt
fileb.txt
listA1.xml
listA.xml
listB1.xml
listB.xml
listC1.xml
listC.xml
name with spaces 2.txt
name with spaces.txt
```

Why is the latter just one-column output but not the multi-column as when there's no redirection to file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-1` is enabled by default when `ls`’s output is redirected.

Strictly speaking, the default output format is `-1`, [as specified in POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ls.html):

> The default format shall be to list one entry per line to standard output; the exceptions are to terminals or when one of the `-C`, `-m`, or `-x` options is specified. If the output is to a terminal, the format is implementation-defined.

You can force columnar output to a file by explicitly specifying `-C`:

```
ls -C > /tmp/ls-C.out
```

Comment: Thanks for the link, 
`. If the output is to a terminal, the format is implementation-defined.`  <<< that's the point not really mentioned in man.

Comment: Man pages describe a specific implementation, so they don’t need to mention that — they can state exactly what the output is when it’s going to a terminal ;-).

Comment: How does `ls` know if the output is a terminal?

Comment: @Jaime it calls [`isatty`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/isatty.html) to check whether its standard output is a terminal.